# Trying to evaluate a registry key display version with less than operator fails

Tags: powershell, variables, operators, version, operands

Registry display version not evaluating correctly when using the less than operator.

Have already tried converting it and tried adding the type accelerator [Version] in front of the version number.

I am using powershell to get registry key properties under `HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\` for a particular software and i store that in a variable `$variable1`:

```
$Variable1 = Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Software Name"
```

After that I use the variable in an if statement to check if the version is less than `11.0.13.xxxxxxxx` (I'm putting the full number).

```
if(($variable1).displayversion -lt "11.0.13.xxxxxxxx")
{
  # do stuff
}
```

but that one evaluates to `false` even though the version installed is `11.0.7.xxxxxxxx`.  I'm guessing its just running the numbers together cause that object is string but when i tried `($variable1).displayversion.toint32()` it fails saying it cant find an overload like im not converting it right.

Is there a better way of doing this?  Or do i need figure out how to convert it to an integer?

Comment: If you like to compare version numbers you should cast these numbers to the proper type ... like this `[Version]'11.0.13.1'` .

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Comment: Ya so when i do (($variable1).DisplayVersion -lt [Version]'11.0.13.xxxxxx') it still evaluates to false even though the version installed is lower.

Comment: You have to cast both sides of the comparison as the right type and you cannot use "xxxx" in it. You have to use a valid version number.

Comment: Maybe that version number can’t be an Int. It has several non-integer characters? You might try getting the minor version numbers (7/13) and comparing them. Again I don’t think integers can have decimals. You can do this with a simple substring or index of.

Comment: @Olaf: Good points, though it's usually sufficient to cast the _LHS_ to the type of interest, as the RHS will be coerced to it.

Comment: no they are all numerical characters just was throwing in x to not go back and forth this is the full version i am using (($Variable1).DisplayVersion -lt [Version]'11.0.13.18102209').  But when i get any of the subkeys by property like that it converts them to system.string.  Maybe cause the Version key is reg sz?

Comment: Integers are whole number. I don’t think they can have decimals. Try comparing a substring since you are working with strings.

Comment: @Keets, based on the preceding comments, does `[version]($Variable1).DisplayVersion -lt '11.0.13.18102209'` not work?

Comment: So ([Version]($Variable1).DisplayVersion -lt [Version]'11.0.13.18102209') still evaluates to false unless im doing it wrong @olaf

Comment: Dang.  Forgot the qotes when i ran it ([Version]($Variable1).DisplayVersion -lt [Version]'11.0.13.18102209') worked.  thanks @Olaf and everyone that helped me on this journey

Comment: @mklement0 ... I'm used to do both sides to make it as declarativ as possible. ;-)

Comment: Nice one. Good to know!

Comment: Ya just running ([Version]($Variable1).DisplayVersion -lt '11.0.13.18102209') worked too, but i figured it would need both since the quotes around the number. @mklement0

Comment: @Olaf, yes, there's certainly no harm in being explicit here. Keets, yes, you need quotes to create an _interim string representation_, given that a literal token such as `11.0.13.18102209` won't work without quotes. The alternative would be to construct a `[version]` instance explicitly: `[version]::new(11, 0, 13, 18102209)` (PSv5+) or `(New-Object System.Version 11, 0, 13, 18102209)`

Answer (score 0):

@KeetsScrimalittle, as Olaf was metioning, you need to cast both as Version to be compared, else its a text comparison.

Solution :

```
$Variable1 = [Version](Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Software Name').DisplayVersion

if( $Variable1 -lt [Version] "11.0.13.00001")
{
 Write-Output "lessthan"
}else {
 Write-Output "morethan"}
```